# TextView width in Table layout android

Tags: android, xml, layout, textview

In my application screen i'm using table layout.in the table row i have two textview.The width of second textview always going out of screen width.I tried wrap_content,match_parent but not getting how to resolve this.How can i set width to device screen layout width?

[image: screen layout]

xml code-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/even" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayoutDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/namerow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nameText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Name" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                     android:background="@android:color/black"
                    android:text="Name :"
                    android:textColor="#808080" />
            </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Even after giving 100dp width to TextView its going outof screen

Comment: Why do you need the weight sum for table row ,remove it and check.

Comment: I tried that one also.it's still same

Comment: Try setting the linear layout widht to wrapcontent

Comment: @amj Tried but not working

Comment: @yuvaツ Fix your TableRow width. if wrap_content means if Child length  increase Parent also will increase.

Comment: Add this attribute to table layout android:shrinkColumns="*", hope this works

Comment: @Yuvaraja I have used match_parent for table row.if i click on table row in xml file its' in the screen only.not going out of screen.but for text view its width is going outof screen

Answer (score 2):

- In your case column #0 is OK, so you just have to **enable shrink** (and stretch too if you like) **for column #1:**

  ```
    <TableLayout ...
        android:shrinkColumns="1"
        android:stretchColumns="1" >
  ```
- You can have a **full explanation** in the main documentation:
  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It may be Android Graphical layout issue. I checked your code in Android View Design. The TextView letters not going Beyond the layout. If you have doubt Set the BackGround to the Text view and see what happened?

Comment: I have updated my image.after setting background to text view it's within screen width.but still text going out of device width

Comment: is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

use this code : work perfect(replace your code with this and modify as your choice)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/include1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvfullname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="#e1e2dd" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Birthday"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvbirth"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="#e1e2dd" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Gender"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvgender"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="#e1e2dd" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Mobile Number"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvmobile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="#e1e2dd" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Email Id"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvemail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="sjdhgvfkasvsjdgfjsgdfjhgskdjfgakjsgdflaghdfljashdgfljadgsfjahg"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="#e1e2dd" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Location"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvlocation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="#e1e2dd" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="City"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvcity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

see this image :

[image]

Comment: I also want scroll view.there are lots of contents

Comment: simply used scroll view...whts the problem